# Is there any way to display an iframe(http) inside a https page using Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, ssl, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to display a webpage inside another page using html-iframe. Works great so far,while using Internet Explorer, but Google Chrome does not display the iFrame, because the page that is displayed is not a https page, while the other one is.

Is there any way to display the http page or do I have to make it a https page?

Answer (score 0):

For your own copy of Chrome, you can run it with `--allow-running-insecure-content` (at which point you shouldn't allow it out on to the WWW).

That isn't practical if you are publish a website for other people. Making the page secure is the correct approach.